# Convergence of $\sum \frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have to choose the right option:

> The series $$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{2n+1}{(n^2+n)^n}$$
>
> ```
>  a. Converges to 1.
>
>  b. Converges to a number >1.
> ```

Using comparison test I can show that this is convergent.

But how to decide whether it converges to 1 or >1?

Comment: What is the first term?

Comment: The first term is for n=1 i.e.3/2. Oh, I get it, so the limit is going to be greater than 1 because 3/2 is greater than 1. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks! I shouldn't have asked this question, its so silly.

Comment: Would you please determine upper and lower bound of sigma?

Answer (score 0):

If it is convergent then its limit must be grater than $1$ because the first term is $\frac{3}{2}.$